# Ionic state reset not working

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I had an older Ionic app, it was built a little bit ago, and I wanted to update some of it and reset the state. I updated the Ionic CLI and Cordova, and then I also did a state reset by doing: `sudo ionic state reset`

Every time I do this I receive this I receive the same error when it tries to update the Ionic keyboard plugin. This error never shows up if I do a state reset before updating the CLI, but it only shows up after. Tried manually adding and removing the plugin but it doesn't show up when using `cordova plugins list` Any help would be nice. Here's the error:

```
Removed platforms and plugins
Attempting to restore your Ionic application from package.json

Restoring Platforms

cordova platform add browser
cordova platform add ios

Restore platforms is complete

Restoring Plugins

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova plugin add com.ionic.keyboard

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/state.js:543
        throw 'Error executing "' + pluginCommand + '":\n' + output;
        ^
Error executing "cordova plugin add com.ionic.keyboard":
Fetching plugin "com.ionic.keyboard" via npm
Error: Failed to fetch plugin com.ionic.keyboard via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com.ionic.keyboard
```

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: Can you specify which plugins were conflicting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you target Cordova 6, make sure that this plugin is supported by the targeted CLI version.

Starting from Cordova 6, VS will only allow or show you plugins that are supported by the targeted CLI version.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It has been updated from **com.ionic.keyboard** to **ionic-plugin-keyboard**, just update it in you package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having the same problem.

I'm running on windows and updated to cordova 6.0.0 and ionic 1.7.14

I got the error initially but then ran Node.js as **Administrator** and then the commands worked, see screen examples;

[image]

Like most things this solution may not be for everyone but I guess no doubt I wont be alone with this issue.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

state has been removed from CLI v3. So on cordova 7 you need to run:

```
ionic cordova prepare
```